# Rails : Undefined method `ref' for ActiveSupport Dependencies:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to install the social stream engine for ruby on rails but I deal with a problem.

I added the

```
 gem 'social_stream'
```

into my GemFile

I did

```
 bundle
```

and when i am giving the command " rails generate social_stream:install " i get the following error :

```
root@cl-t178-481cl [/home/ruby/www/network]# rails generate social_stream:install
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/devise-1.1.9/lib/devise.rb:193:in `mailer=':     undefined method `ref' for ActiveSupport::Dependencies:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/devise-1.1.9/lib/devise.rb:195:in `<module:Devise>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/devise-1.1.9/lib/devise.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/social_stream-0.0.5/lib/social_stream/rails.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/social_stream-0.0.5/lib/social_stream.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/social_stream-0.0.5/lib/social_stream.rb:53:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.6.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.6.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.6.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.6.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.6.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.6.0.pre.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/bundler-1.6.0.pre.1/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /home/ruby/public_html/network/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I am using Rails 3.2.13
and ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [i686-linux]

Comment: I have seen this thread. It is not related to my problem as i have the correct rails version

Comment: You didn't read the entire thing. The problem stemmed from the Devise gem. Do you have a known working version Devise?

Comment: I have read that too and tried it. It didn't work. I knew that ImageMagick was also missing from my server, i installed it and everything worked again.